# Setting scroller on template element

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, mobiscroll

I am using mobiscroll with underscore.  I have an underscore template. I need to do the .scroller on an element added from the template.

Here is the template:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate"/>
</form>
```

Here is the render function in the view:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: render('auctioncreate'),
    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty().append(this.template);
        $('#startdate').scroller();  // this does not work
    }
});
```

render is a function that loads the html and makes it into a template.  For completeness, here is the code for the render function:

```
function render(tn, td) {
    if(!render.tc) {
        render.tc = {};
    }
    if(! render.tc[tn]) {
        var td = 'assets/js/templates';
        var tu = td + "/" + tn + ".html";
        var ts;
        $.ajax({
            url: tu,
            method: 'GET',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(d) {
                ts = d;
            },
            error: function(e) {
            }
        });
        render.tc[tn] = ts;
    }
    return _.template(render.tc[tn]);
}
```

I have tried adding a ondomready javascript in the template itself.  It does not work straight away, but it does work after a refresh?!

```
$(function() {
    $('#startdate').scroller(); // this work if I refresh once.
});
```

Basically I need to apply the datetime picker on the element after it gets appended to the dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in the render function of the View.

Instead of:

```
$('#startdate')...
```

It should have been:

```
this.$('#startdate')...
```